# Gave up waiting for root device ubuntu 14.10

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 (kernel v3.16.0-23)
I am new to Linux environment and learning how to compile-install-boot new kernel image.

I downloaded kernel 3.17.2. Compiled and built the same. Followed the below sequence of commands:

```
make menuconfig
make
make modules_install
make install
update-initramfs -c -k 3.17.2
update-grub
```

And then after reboot, I am not able to boot into newly built kernel. See below error:

```
**early console in decompress_kernel
Decompressing Linux... Parsing ELF... done.
Booting the kernel.
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cats /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/c519ae92-164a-4078-b687-2b4734166533 does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-8ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help'for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

But I am still able to boot into original version (3.16.0-23)

Could anyone help me to resolve this? I tried couple of solutions available but no success.

Thanks.

Comment: I have limited experience with this, mainly just recompiling kernels with i7 optimizations. However, it appears that the kernel built, but all the modules are missing which may mean that it's not able to find the disk because the modules aren't loaded? Is there anything in /lib/modules/3.17.2?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I can say that it seems that you have disabled the passing of boot arguments during boot feature of the kernel. That is why kernel is not getting arguments ans booting into terminal